# Virustotal alerts for Surfshark VPN

Tags: malware, vpn, virus, trojan

Virustotal is giving some alerts for the Windows installation of Surfshark VPN. I am sure they are false positives, I just wanted to hear what other users say about this...
[image]

Comment: that is the updated hash signature, only option is to whitelist the application

Comment: For questions like this, please go to the vendors forum. It is off topic here.